# PowerShell PnP Script to loop thru all WebPart Location Terms

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

We need a SharePoint PnP PowerShell Script to loop through all the WebPart Location Terms and query to see if it is used recently or not.

So far I have tried to build a PowerShell script to get all the Terms in the Term in TermSet Location. Got all the Terms in it, but was informed we need update the code to pull all the WebPart location Terms. This I have no clue on how to proceed.

```
Connect-PnPOnline $siteurl
Get-PnPTerm -TermSet "Location" -TermStore "Taxonomy" -TermGroup "People" | Select PathOfTerm, Name, ID, Owner, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate | Export-CSV "C:/Terms/Terms1.csv"
```

Once I got the list I have to loop through them to with `Submit-PnPSearchQuery` method to see if it returns any rows. If it did, we have to remove those that are not listed. So far I was able to pull the list of all the terms in "Location" but not sure what does WebPart Location Terms means.

Please help me on how to pull the records of the WebPart Location Terms with SharePoint PnP PowerShell script, I can then figure out on how to find if its used or not. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to figure this out by myself:

I was able to pull all the terms and it’s children terms from the webpart location term.
The problem I had is I was using wrong `TermSet`. After fixing that with the below code, I was able to pull the list of all the terms and children terms in the required termset

```
Connect-PnPOnline $siteurl
$terms = Get-PnPTerm -TermSet “Webpart Locations” -TermGroup “People”
foreach ($term in $terms) {
    $cText = $term.Context
    $cText.Load($term.Terms)
    $cText.ExecuteQuery()
    $term.Terms | Select ID, Name, PathOfTerm, Owner, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate | Export-CSV “C:\TermList.csv”
```

I also tried to find if the terms are used or not by the below code on the `$term.Terms`

```
Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query “IsReused:False”  -All
```

It returned all the Terms in the csv, after this checked the csv and found the CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate are equal.
So concluded that we have to figure out other ways to find if the Term is used in the SharePoint page by the user or not.

Hope this helps someone someday!
Thank you!